# How do I make webcam view fullscreen on mobile webapp

Tags: javascript, html, css, progressive-web-apps, webcam

I am trying to stretch my webcam view to fullscreen but I can't seem to get it right without losing quality or the image being stretched.

What styling should I use to achieve this or do I need to write some javascript to help?

so far all I have is the following:

```
#CSS FILE
/* Camera */
#videoElement {
    /*width: 500px;*/
    /*height: 100%;*/
    min-height:100%;

    background-color: #666;
}

#HTML FILE
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></video>
```

Comment: You cannot force a video to be full screen, the user can make it fullscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using view height to 100%, this gets me around a lot of these issues.

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp

```
/*CSS*/
{
  width: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work this best so far  I'm gonna keep this open just for another day to see if someone else has other solutions so they can post her. But definitely did what I wanted. Now to center it and remove the scroll option 

Comment: vh works good. like i said, i get a lot of these types of issues and it is a good tool to use.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting only the width of `#videoElement` to `width: 100%`.

So the CSS would go like:

```
 #videoElement 
 {
   width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't display the whole thing how a phone camera app would in fullscreen mode

Answer (score 1):

Add this attribute to video tag

```
 webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"
```

Comment: Full screen doesn't mean the entire browser, it means the entire window, without the browser chrome

Comment: @JuanMendes you understood explained what I wanted better than I did 

Comment: @MarcoFernandes I almost understood what this comment means  Are you saying you were just asking for the video to take up the entire browser? If you did, that has nothing to do with video specifically. Any tag would have the same solution. Either way, both questions already have answers here at stack overflow.

Comment: @JuanMendes I basically just want a user to open the website on the phone and the camera takes up the whole screen. Not allowing the user to scroll the browser or anything. Basically trying to replicate what a normal phone camera app would do but thru a website. I know the best approach would probably be to build a flutter app but this app is so basic that I want to build I want to do it all as a progressive web app.